# BugReport, отлов ошибок и т.п. - Ваши решения/наработки

Tags: php

День добрый!

Поделитесь своими секретами и наработками **работы с ошибками в PHP**. 
Пользователь не всегда сообщит о том что он увидел ошибку на сайте, да и стандартный отчет об ошибке его скорее всего напугает.

- Какими способами отправляете ошибки ?
- Где храните отчеты?(фалы, БД,сторонние сервисы)
- Какой интерфейс используете для оповещения пользователя и обратной связи его(пользователя) с адмнинистратором сайта ?
- Какие есть готовые инструменты и как их "готовить"?

Буду очень признателен всем за ответы, так как встал вопрос :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Свои "наработки" я расположил в порядке убивания приоритета (т.е. пунктом 1 я пользуюсь чаще всего, пунктом 3 - реже).

1. Таблица Log в БД. Реализация произвольная. В админке сайта где-то ссылка на страницу, где `findAll` из этой таблицы (для некоторых сайтов с возможностью `CRUD`'a).
2. Для `crucial bugs - email` разработчику(ам).
3. Для более массовых логов (куда будут стекаться миллионы строк в день) - `file logging`.

Т.к. я использую [фреймворк Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging)